# Comparing two means

Tags: statistical-significance, mean

I have a question on comparing means and I would be really thankful if you could help...
I have a data set that contains responses from a questionnaire (so one group only, N=216). The questionnaire forms 3 scales (A,B,C).

My means for these scales are: 
A:mean=14.92, with SD=6.96 
B:mean=10.51, with SD=7.32
C:mean=14.04, with SD=11.12

I would like to compare these three means to see which scale is higher (where people scored higher). What should I do? Should I first transform my data into z-scores before making comparison? 
Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: are these three scales sub-constructs or each one of these is so-called equivalent to each other implying that three (scales) are competing with other

Comment: You should not transform to z-scores! A common approach if you want to do hypothesis testing would be to use ANOVA to test for equality of means.

Answer (score 1):

You want a repeated measures ANOVA, where the scales are the repeated measures. Then you can perform contrasts between scales to see which are higher.